# PCI Compliance with Native Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pci-compliance

We have PostgreSQL database no 3rd party software a Linux ad min and a SQL dba with little PostgreSQL experience.

We need to set up audit\access logging of all transactions on the CC tables.  We enabled logging, but we are concerned about enabling everything to log. We want to restrict it to specified tables.  I am not finding a resource that I under stand to accomplish this.

a few blogs have mentioned table triggers and logfiles

I found another that discusses functions.  I am just not sure how t proceed on this. The following is the PCI information I am working off of:

1. (Done) Install pg_stat_statements extension to monitor all queries (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
2. Setup monitor to find out suspicious access on PAN holding table
3. Enable connection/disconnection logging
4. Enable Web Server access logs
5. Monitor Postgres logs for unsuccessful login attempts
6. Automated log analysis  &  Access Monitoring using Alerts
7. Keep archive audit and log history for at least one year and for last 3 
   months ready available for analysis

**Update**

also need to apply password policy to postgrsql db users.

1. 90 day expirations (there is a place to set a date but not an
   interval)
2. Lock out user 6 failed attempts Locked out for 30 minutes
   or until an administrator enables the userID.
3. Force re-authenticate when idle for more than 15 minutes
4. Passwords/phrases must meet the
   following: Require a minimum length of at least seven characters.
   Contain both numeric and alphabetic characters.
5. Cannot be same as last 4 passwords/passphrases used

Comment: Usually your credit card vendor will have a check-list of hundreds of things you must do to comply. Have you gone through that process? If this is of critical business importance you should probably hire a consultant who's certified to audit your system.

Answer (score 1):

2) There is no direct way to log access to tables. The extension [pg_audit](https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit/blob/master/README.md#user-content-settings) claims that it can do that. I have never used it though.

3) can easily be done using [log_connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-CONNECTIONS) and [log_disconnections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-DISCONNECTIONS)

4) has nothing to do with Postgres

5) can be done once connection logging has been done by monitoring the logfile

6) no idea what that should mean

7) that is independent of the Postgres setup. You just need to make sure the Postgres logfiles are archived properly.